# Overload of QtGui.QLabel.setNum in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, overload-resolution

In PyQt4, the slot QtGui.QLabel.setNum is overloaded.

We have `setNum( int )`  and `setNum( float )`, linking to their c++ counterparts `setNum( int)` and `setNum( double)`.

I would like to connect a signal to the "float" version.

```
label = QLabel()
slider = QwtSlider()
slider.valueChanged[float].connect(label.setNum)
```

Unfortunately, the slot that seems to be called is the `int` version.

My only workaround so far is

```
slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda x: label.setText(str(x)))
```

Is there a simple way to force the call of the float overload of setNum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use another form of `connect`:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(slider, QtCore.SIGNAL('setNum(double)'), <...>)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using your approach seems to give the same result. More precely, I wrote:
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.Slider, QtCore.SIGNAL('valueChanged (double)'), self.ui.label_2,  QtCore.SLOT('setNum (double)'))
and I am still getting integers.